# adding a calculation into a update Query in oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-update

i have the following table

```
----------
Mass | Nett | NetDecrease | Mass_difference
5000 |4500  | 1200        |
```

i want to update my Mass and NetDecrease columns as follows

```
update table t
set t.Mass=6000 // this will be a parameter passed in
    t.NetDecrease=t.Mass - t.Nett
where // where conditions enetred in here
```

now what im not ceratin about is in the Mass_difference column i need to take the current mass thats in the table and minus it by the new mass.
for instance the current mass is 5000 and the new mass passed in is 6000 so it should be

```
t.Mass_Difference =currentMass- NewMass
```

how ever in the update statement the mass is already been updated to 6000,which i need to calculate the netDecrease.
So how would do i store the current mass temporally so i can calculate the difference?

Comment: Re-use the parameter: `t.Mass_Difference = t.mass - 6000`

Comment: the t.mass is already updated to 6000

Comment: The reference to `t.mass` on the right hand side of the assignment is evaluated _before_ updating the column. This **will** work, e.g. `update foo set x = y, y = x` will work for the same reason

Comment: so u saying it should be Set t.mass= 6000, t.Mass_diferrence = t.mass - 6000?

Comment: Yes, you are already doing that for `netdecrease`

Comment: Why don't you just run both cases and test which result is what you expect? It is the best way of learning.